# How to find the value with date closest to another date

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I work in healthcare, and need to produce a report that shows patient lab values at various timepoints.  The timepoints are like the following:

Pre transplant:

1 year = 365 days +/- 30 days

3 months = 90 days +/- 14 days

1 month = 30 days +/- 7 days

Post transplant:

1 day = 24 hrs +/- 12 hrs

1 week = 7 days +/- 1 days

1 month = 30 days +/- 7 days

3 month = 90 days +/- 14 days

6 month = 180 days +/- 30 days

1 year = 365 days +/- 30 days

My data model has a lot of tables (results from SQL Server queries), but the main lab table looks like the following:

```
+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| Order ID | Episode ID | Transplant Date | Lab Date   | Lab Value |
+----------+------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| 111      | 222        | 5/2/2018        | 1/22/2018  | 23        |
| 112      | 222        | 5/2/2018        | 1/27/2018  | 15        |
| 113      | 222        | 5/2/2018        | 5/3/2018   | 14        |
| 114      | 222        | 5/2/2018        | 10/19/2018 | 12        |
| 115      | 223        | 1/23/2019       | 1/24/2019  | 20        |
| 116      | 223        | 1/23/2019       | 1/25/2019  | 25        |
| 117      | 223        | 1/23/2019       | 1/31/2019  | 29        |
| 118      | 223        | 1/23/2019       | 4/23/2019  | 30        |
| 119      | 223        | 1/23/2019       | 3/1/2019   | 35        |
| 120      | 224        | 7/19/2019       | 7/19/2018  | 5         |
| 121      | 224        | 7/19/2019       | 7/24/2018  | 13        |
+-----------------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
```

`Order ID` is the unique identifier for the lab, `Episode ID` is the unique identifier for the patient, and we're looking for labs relative to the `Transplant Date`.

There's another table for patient data that looks something like this:

```
+------------+----------------+-----------------+
| Episode ID | Patient Name   | Transplant Date |
+------------+----------------+-----------------+
| 222        | Alphers, Ralph | 5/2/2018        |
| 223        | Bethe, Hans    | 1/23/2019       |
| 224        | Gammow, George | 7/19/2019       |
+------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

The resulting data should looke similar to this:

```
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+
| Episode ID | 1 year pre | 3 months pre | 1 month pre | 1 day post | 1 week post | 1 month post | 6 months post | 1 year post |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+
| 222        |            | 15           |             | 14         |             |              | 12            |             |
| 223        |            |              |             | 20         | 29          | 35           |               |             |
| 224        | 5          |              |             |            |             |              |               |             |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+
```

**Is there a best way to do this, taking into account both processing time (user experience) and development complexity?**

Right now, here's how I'm doing it.

First, I'm using Power Query (M) to create the time points (e.g.  `Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Minutes to One Year Before Transplant", each Number.Abs(Duration.TotalMinutes(([Lab Date] - DateTime.From(Date.AddYears([Transplant Date], -1))))))`).
Then, I use DAX to find the number of days for the record that's closest to the right target date:

```
Labs shortest minutes to one year before transplant = 
VAR EpisodeID = Patients[Episode ID]
VAR TargetDate = DATEADD(Patients[Transplant Date], 1, MONTH)
VAR WindowDays = 30
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    MIN(Labs[Minutes to One Month After Transplant]),
    FILTER(Labs, Labs[Episode ID] = EpisodeID),
    FILTER(Labs, Labs[Lab Date] >= DATEADD(TargetDate, -WindowDays, DAY)),
    FILTER(Labs, Labs[Lab Date] <= DATEADD(TargetDate, WindowDays, DAY))
)
```

Then, I use that number of minutes as an identifier to grab the `Order ID`

```
Lab Order ID closest to one year before transplant = 
VAR EpisodeID = Patients[Episode ID]
VAR TargetDate = DATEADD(Patients[Transplant Date], 1, MONTH)
VAR WindowDays = 30
VAR DaysFrom = Patients[Labs shortest minutes to one year before transplant]
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    MIN(Labs[Order ID]),
    FILTER(Labs, Labs[Episode ID] = EpisodeID),
    FILTER(Labs, Labs[Lab Date] >= DATEADD(TargetDate, -WindowDays, DAY)),
    FILTER(Labs, Labs[Lab Date] <= DATEADD(TargetDate, WindowDays, DAY))
)
```

Finally, I can use that `Order ID` to grab whatever I want from that lab, like the value:

```
Lab Value closest to one year before transplant = 
VAR EpisodeID = Patients[Episode ID]
VAR OrderID = Patients[Lab Order ID closest to one year before transplant]
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    MIN(Labs[Value]),
    FILTER(Labs, Labs[Episode ID] = EpisodeID),
    FILTER(Labs, Labs[Order ID] = OrderID)
)
```

And, I need to do this for 3 different labs, which means repeating this process like 30 times.  And, the resulting report takes awhile to do the calculations.  I can push a bunch of work back to SQL Server, but maybe that's not the best idea?

Comment: When there are multiple matching results, which do you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The combination of `Lab Date` and `Value` should be unique for each `Episode ID`, but if not, just take the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding a different answer due to the response to the previous answer about the data.

I would make a table with buckets that dates fall in.  This way if someone requests different buckets it is simple to add.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_Buckets](
    [Bucket] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NumDaysLow] [int] NULL,
    [NumDaysHigh] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table_Buckets] ([Bucket], [NumDaysLow], [NumDaysHigh]) VALUES (N'Pre-1Yr', -395, -335)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table_Buckets] ([Bucket], [NumDaysLow], [NumDaysHigh]) VALUES (N'Pre-3Mth', -105, -75)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table_Buckets] ([Bucket], [NumDaysLow], [NumDaysHigh]) VALUES (N'Pre-1Mth', -37, -21)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table_Buckets] ([Bucket], [NumDaysLow], [NumDaysHigh]) VALUES (N'Post-1Day', 0, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table_Buckets] ([Bucket], [NumDaysLow], [NumDaysHigh]) VALUES (N'Post-1Wk', 6, 8)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table_Buckets] ([Bucket], [NumDaysLow], [NumDaysHigh]) VALUES (N'Post-1Mth', 21, 37)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table_Buckets] ([Bucket], [NumDaysLow], [NumDaysHigh]) VALUES (N'Post-3Mth', 76, 104)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table_Buckets] ([Bucket], [NumDaysLow], [NumDaysHigh]) VALUES (N'Post-6Mth', 150, 210)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table_Buckets] ([Bucket], [NumDaysLow], [NumDaysHigh]) VALUES (N'Post-1Yr', 335, 395)
GO
```

Now you can run the following sql query that will take the data, put a bucket date to the episode, take the lowest number per bucket and then pivot the table to the view that you desire.  You will have to design your data around this structure.

```
select
   EpisodeID
  ,[Pre-1Yr]
  ,[Pre-3Mth]
  ,[Pre-1Mth]
  ,[Post-1Day]
  ,[Post-1Wk]
  ,[Post-1Mth]
  ,[Post-3Mth]
  ,[Post-6Mth]
  ,[Post-1Yr]

from 
(
  --this select statement takes the lowest value if there are more than one value per bucket
  select main.EpisodeID, main.Bucket, min(main.LabValue) as LabValue from
    (--this select statement assigns the episode to a buckets 
     select
        ml.EpisodeID
        , (select Bucket from
                table_Buckets
            where 
                    NumDaysLow  <= datediff(d,pd.TransplantDate, ml.LabDate)
                and NumDaysHigh >= datediff(d,pd.TransplantDate, ml.LabDate)
            ) AS Bucket
        , ml.LabValue as LabValue

    from 
        table_MainLab ML, 
        table_PatientData PD where ml.EpisodeID = pd.EpisodeID
    ) main
group by EpisodeID, Bucket) s


pivot
(avg(LabValue)
for [Bucket] in
  ([Pre-1Yr]
  ,[Pre-3Mth]
  ,[Pre-1Mth]
  ,[Post-1Day]
  ,[Post-1Wk]
  ,[Post-1Mth]
  ,[Post-3Mth]
  ,[Post-6Mth]
  ,[Post-1Yr])
 ) as pivottable
```

I am new to posting and I have not figured out how to put the output in this post :(...I will practice

Comment: L. - I marked this as the answer, since it does solve the immediate issue.  I was kinda hoping for a magic DAX or M function, but this is probably the best way to do it.  My dream was some kind of dashboard that allows the user to put in a date point and the date window, and the labs displayed would magically update to the lab closest to that timepoint within the window.  That way, when the next client wants a different timepoint than those already hard-coded, I wouldn't have to go in and modify the SQL.  But, that's probably too much to ask right now.  Thanks Jim!

Comment: You could keep the same SQL and create a temporary table for each client that will SELECT from the temp table instead of the table_Buckets.  This is the original intent of the table_Buckets, if the scope changes you would just amend the data in that table.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of, is to create calculated columns for each time period and then use them directly in whatever measure you want. For example, for 1 year pre:

```
1 Year Pre = IF('Table'[Lab Date]>='Table'[Transplant Date]-395 && 'Table'[Lab Date]<='Table'[Transplant Date]-335,'Table'[LabValue],BLANK())
```

for 3 months pre:

```
3 Months Pre = IF('Table'[Lab Date]>='Table'[Transplant Date]-104 && 'Table'[Lab Date]<='Table'[Transplant Date]-76,'Table'[LabValue],BLANK())
```

Similarly, you could create calculated columns for other time periods as well and use them to get the desired visual. Hope this helps.

Comment: This will flag each lab row that falls within the timepoint date window, but it will not flag which lab is closest to the exact timepoint, which is what I need.  Also, I could probably do some pre-work by either creating these columns in Power Query (M), or just hard-coding it into the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

All of your code is M, so I'm not sure why you tagged this with SQL.  But here's [probably not the most elegant] SQL solution:

```
create table labs (
    OrderID int not null,
    EpisodeID int not null,
    TransplantDate date not null,
    LabDate date not null,
    LabValue int not null)

insert labs
values 
(111, 222, cast('5/2/2018'  as date), cast('1/22/2018'  as date), 23),
(112, 222, cast('5/2/2018'  as date), cast('1/27/2018'  as date), 15),
(113, 222, cast('5/2/2018'  as date), cast('5/3/2018'   as date), 14),
(114, 222, cast('5/2/2018'  as date), cast('10/19/2018' as date), 12),
(115, 223, cast('1/23/2019' as date), cast('1/24/2019'  as date), 20),
(116, 223, cast('1/23/2019' as date), cast('1/25/2019'  as date), 25),
(117, 223, cast('1/23/2019' as date), cast('1/31/2019'  as date), 29),
(118, 223, cast('1/23/2019' as date), cast('4/23/2019'  as date), 30),
(119, 223, cast('1/23/2019' as date), cast('3/1/2019'   as date), 35),
(120, 224, cast('7/19/2019' as date), cast('7/19/2018'  as date),  5),
(121, 224, cast('7/19/2019' as date), cast('7/24/2018'  as date), 13)

create table patient (
    EpisodeID int not null,
    PatientName varchar(128) not null,
    TransplantDate date not null
)

insert patient
values
(222, 'Alphers, Ralph', cast('5/2/2018'  as date)),
(223, 'Bethe, Hans',    cast('1/23/2019' as date)),
(224, 'Gammow, George', cast('7/19/2019' as date))


select q.EpisodeID
, min(q.[1YrPre]  ) as '1YrPre'
, min(q.[3MoPre]  ) as '3MoPre'
, min(q.[1MoPre]  ) as '1MoPre'
, min(q.[1DayPost]) as '1DayPost'
, min(q.[1WkPost] ) as '1WkPost'
, min(q.[1MoPost] ) as '1MoPost'
, min(q.[3MoPost] ) as '3MoPost'
, min(q.[6MoPost] ) as '6MoPost'
, min(q.[1YrPost] ) as '1YrPost'

from (
    select r.OrderID
    , r.EpisodeID
    , case when r.[1YrPreCheck]   = m.[1YrPreCheck]   and m.[1YrPreCheck]   <= 30 then r.LabValue end as '1YrPre'
    , case when r.[3MoPreCheck]   = m.[3MoPreCheck]   and m.[3MoPreCheck]   <= 14 then r.LabValue end as '3MoPre'
    , case when r.[1MoPreCheck]   = m.[1MoPreCheck]   and m.[1MoPreCheck]   <=  7 then r.LabValue end as '1MoPre'
    , case when r.[1DayPostCheck] = m.[1DayPostCheck] and m.[1DayPostCheck] <=  1 then r.LabValue end as '1DayPost'
    , case when r.[1WkPostCheck]  = m.[1WkPostCheck]  and m.[1WkPostCheck]  <=  1 then r.LabValue end as '1WkPost'
    , case when r.[1MoPostCheck]  = m.[1MoPostCheck]  and m.[1MoPostCheck]  <=  7 then r.LabValue end as '1MoPost'
    , case when r.[6MoPostCheck]  = m.[3MoPostCheck]  and m.[3MoPostCheck]  <= 14 then r.LabValue end as '3MoPost'
    , case when r.[6MoPostCheck]  = m.[6MoPostCheck]  and m.[6MoPostCheck]  <= 30 then r.LabValue end as '6MoPost'
    , case when r.[1YrPostCheck]  = m.[1YrPostCheck]  and m.[1YrPostCheck]  <= 30 then r.LabValue end as '1YrPost'

    from (
        select p.EpisodeID
        , min(abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(year,  -1, p.TransplantDate)))) as '1YrPreCheck'
        , min(abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(month, -3, p.TransplantDate)))) as '3MoPreCheck'
        , min(abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(month, -1, p.TransplantDate)))) as '1MoPreCheck'
        , min(abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(day,    1, p.TransplantDate)))) as '1DayPostCheck'
        , min(abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(day,    7, p.TransplantDate)))) as '1WkPostCheck'
        , min(abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(month,  1, p.TransplantDate)))) as '1MoPostCheck'
        , min(abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(month,  3, p.TransplantDate)))) as '3MoPostCheck'
        , min(abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(month,  6, p.TransplantDate)))) as '6MoPostCheck'
        , min(abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(year,   1, p.TransplantDate)))) as '1YrPostCheck'

        from labs l
          inner join patient p on p.EpisodeID = l.EpisodeID

        group by p.EpisodeID
    ) m
      inner join (
        select l.OrderID
        , p.EpisodeID
        , l.LabValue
        , abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(year,  -1, p.TransplantDate))) as '1YrPreCheck'
        , abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(month, -3, p.TransplantDate))) as '3MoPreCheck'
        , abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(month, -1, p.TransplantDate))) as '1MoPreCheck'
        , abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(day,    1, p.TransplantDate))) as '1DayPostCheck'
        , abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(day,    7, p.TransplantDate))) as '1WkPostCheck'
        , abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(month,  1, p.TransplantDate))) as '1MoPostCheck'
        , abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(month,  3, p.TransplantDate))) as '3MoPostCheck'
        , abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(month,  6, p.TransplantDate))) as '6MoPostCheck'
        , abs(datediff(day, l.LabDate, dateadd(year,   1, p.TransplantDate))) as '1YrPostCheck'

        from labs l
      inner join patient p on p.EpisodeID = l.EpisodeID
    ) r on r.EpisodeID = m.EpisodeID
)q 

group by q.EpisodeID
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put this under comments but I need more reputation points before I can comment.  Maybe a moderator can move this for me.

To begin,

1 - You need to identify what to do when a lab does not fall in any of the buckets described above.  For example, what would you do if the lab date is at 6 months.  Where would you like a 6 month lab to be reported? In your example above you lost some data from EpisodeID 222.  In my experience, you should report it somewhere - even if it is a catchall bucket that needs to be investigated.

2 - You will need to identify what you want to do when you have 2 reports for the same time period.  With EpisodeID 222 you will see that you have 2 Labs in the pre-90 day period.   Jan 22 and Jan 27 will both fall in that period.

3 - You have similar data in two tables.  The TransplantDate should only be in your PatientTable

You're best bet is a simple pivot (crosstab) query. If you can define your data better by answering 1 and 2 above you will be further ahead to get this done.

Comment: Hi @Jim L.  1. Yes, data will fall through the cracks.  I'm putting in another report tab that shows all labs for each patient.  The requestor wants one report that shows specifically these timepoints, though.  2. They want the one lab that is closest to the timepoint.  If there's somehow a tie, take the first one.  The point is, one lab value per timepoint.  3. Yeah, that was to make it a little easier to make some kind of timepoint flag in the Labs table.  It's still complicated as hell, though!  Thank you for the clarifying questions.

Comment: I posted new results as an answer